# How can I get Microsoft Edge to open .sty files by default?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Right now, to get Edge to open .sty files, I need to 1) download the file 2) copy the path of the downloaded file 3) paste the path into the address bar, and then Edge opens it.

How can I get Edge to just open the file directly, instead of download it separately first?

Comment: Right Click - Open With - Select Edge

Comment: @Ramhound I struggled with that (since it seems hard to find Edge in the list of programs that can open .sty files) but I'm actually even more interested in the thing that happens before that - if I were to navigate (using Edge) to a website that had lots of .sty files to download, at present if I click on the .sty files, I download them. I'd rather Edge just open the .sty file on that particular Edge window.

Comment: That isn’t possible, the reason you can open a pdf file, is edge is an actual pdf reader. It’s not by default a .sty reader.

Comment: @Ramhound Can I set it to be a .sty reader?

Comment: Chromium, which is open source, could be made into an editor if you have the programming knowledge to do so otherwise unless Microsoft adds it as a feature then it cannot be a .sty reader by default. Why don’t you just use a text editor?